# ajax error only first request is send

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('#show_mess').click(function (){
        $('#dropdown_mess').slideToggle("slow");
        $('#arrow_mess').slideToggle("slow");
        $('#arrow_not').hide("slow");
        $('#dropdown_not').hide("slow");

        function recall(){ setTimeout(function () {  

        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/ajax/mess_data.php", true);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                                document.getElementById('dropdown_mess').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            }       
                    }

                xmlhttp.send();
                document.getElementById('dropdown_mess').innerHTML = "<img class='non_auto' id='ajax_loading' src='img/ajax_loading.gif'></img>";

                recall();

                }, 2000);
            }; 

                recall();
    });
```

this function works fine but when each ajax call is done i need to colse and re-oper chrome in order to work, works fine in firefox

Comment: why don't you use jquery $.ajax function? It's crossbrowser and more convenient.

Comment: Please show your code in the context of the HTML you are using it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using Jquery so why don't you try it's ajax function like below

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() {
    ....
});
```

You can find more information on the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: how to save context: document.body in a var?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to add context option at all.